# Is there a way to give promo/coupon codes for in-game items (non-paid) to people?

Tags: android, coupon, promotion-code

I want to give my users (which follow me on Twitter or Facebook) promo codes for locked themes in my game. Themes are locked by default, but not paid. They can be unlocked by doing certain things in game or using a promo code.

Questions I saw about promo codes were all about paid apps and in-app purchases so I couldn't relate to them. Does Google allow this kind of action? If not, what is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: While the solution in fine will be programmed, the initial problem is about solution design, and will not be solve here. See [ask].

Comment: I assume you could follow those same methodologies that you discovered for paid elements and charge $0.00 as an option.

Comment: @Jay Snayder, But the point is to give the promo codes from Facebook and Twitter in order to motivate users to follow our page.